# A PL/SQl program to know whether the given date is a weekend or not

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

```
set serveroutput on

DECLARE
    b VARCHAR2(10);
    CURSOR a IS
    SELECT
        hiredate
    FROM
        emp;

BEGIN
    FOR i IN a LOOP
        b := to_char(i.hiredate, 'DAY');
        dbms_output.put_line(to_char(i.hiredate, 'DAY'));
        IF b in ('SATURDAY','SUNDAY') THEN
            dbms_output.put_line('It is a weekend');
        END IF;

    END LOOP;
END;
/
```

I tried to run this code, but I am not getting whether the date is a weekend or not. Please help me to find the error and explain the logic behind it.

Here is the output

```
WEDNESDAY
FRIDAY   
SUNDAY   
THURSDAY 
MONDAY   
FRIDAY   
TUESDAY  
THURSDAY 
TUESDAY  
TUESDAY  
WEDNESDAY
THURSDAY 
THURSDAY 
SATURDAY 

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

WEDNESDAY
FRIDAY   
SUNDAY
It is a weekend   
THURSDAY 
MONDAY   
FRIDAY   
TUESDAY  
THURSDAY 
TUESDAY  
TUESDAY  
WEDNESDAY
THURSDAY 
THURSDAY 
SATURDAY 
It is a weekend

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

Comment: For weekends specifically, I'd use `if to_char(somedate,'DY','nls_date_language=English') like 'S%'`. The right-padding behaviour of the DAY format catches a lot of people out, and you don't need the full name anyway, because in English (note that you should always specify the language when using language-specific names) the two weekend days are the only ones that begin with 'S'. However, you may need a different rule for territories with different weekend conventions.

Answer (score 3):

You got *nothing* because of a wrong format model. `DAY` right-pads the result with spaces, up to the longest day in a week. In other words, this is what you got:

```
SQL> select '#' || to_char(sysdate, 'DAY') || '#' day from dual;

DAY
--------------------------------------
#SUNDAY   #
```

See all those spaces? You should've trimmed them or - better - use correct format model:

```
SQL> select '#' || to_char(sysdate, 'fmDAY') || '#' day from dual;

DAY
--------------------------------------
#SUNDAY#

SQL>
```

---

As of your question, it would probably be better to create a **function** you can then call from wherever you want.

```
SQL> create or replace function f_weekend (par_date in date) return varchar2 is
  2  begin
  3    return case when to_char(par_date, 'fmDAY', 'nls_date_language = english') in
  4                     ('SATURDAY', 'SUNDAY')
  5                then
  6                     ' is a weekend'
  7                else null
  8           end;
  9  end;
 10  /

Function created.
```

Testing:

```
SQL> select ename, to_char(hiredate, 'dd.mm.yyyy, fmDay') hiredate,
  2         f_weekend(hiredate) weekend
  3  from emp;

ENAME      HIREDATE                       WEEKEND
---------- ------------------------------ --------------------
SMITH      17.12.1980, Wednesday
ALLEN      20.02.1981, Friday
WARD       22.02.1981, Sunday              is a weekend
JONES      02.04.1981, Thursday
MARTIN     28.09.1981, Monday
BLAKE      01.05.1981, Friday
CLARK      09.06.1981, Tuesday
SCOTT      09.12.1982, Thursday
KING       17.11.1981, Tuesday
TURNER     08.09.1981, Tuesday
ADAMS      12.01.1983, Wednesday
JAMES      03.12.1981, Thursday
FORD       03.12.1981, Thursday
MILLER     23.01.1982, Saturday            is a weekend

14 rows selected.

SQL>
```